# 64-bit x264 & 32-bit Avisynth YUY2?

Tags: avisynth, x264

Currently, I have Avisynth file that output YUY2 Color space, and I want to encode it in High 4:2:2 Profile H.264.

Since my Avisynth filter isn't available in 64-bit yet, I have to use 32-bit Avisynth. I can encode it perfectly with 32-bit x264. But the 32-bit version is slower. If I use 64-bit x264, the encoder cannot load 32-bit Avisynth, and I have to pipe in.

If I am encoding in standard HiP/Hi10P profile, I can use avs2yuv, which generate YV12 raw to pipe into x264. But I cannot find any program which can pipe YUY2 colorspace (or i422 color space)

**Question**: Is there a way to use 64-bit x264 with 32-bit Avisynth and 4:2:2 output? Standard avs2yuv doesn't support 4:2:2, and 64-bit x264 cannot load 32-bit Avisynth directly.

---

PS. I usually downscale 1080p > 720p so the additional colour information is preserved.

PS2. I know I can playback High 4:2:2 file. My LAV Video Decoder & madVR can play it beautifully.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, should be clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Try avs4x26x v0.10.0 or newer to pipe your AviSynth output.

http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=162656

https://github.com/astrataro/avs4x26x